# which modifiers to apply

Tags: modifiers

General questions
How do you remember which modifier to apply or not ?
A lot of time in tutorial videos, people say “ don’t apply it” but sometimes it doesn’t work if you don’t apply it right?
What’s the purpose of leaving apply?

Comment: By Applying modifier you loose non-destructive way of modelling ... Can you refer some  situation or tutorial asking you to apply modifier? The only reason that comes to my mind at the moment is a case you need to adjust some vertices manually or you need to access some specific vertices via vertex group or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each case is different, don't apply if you don't need to, apply if you need, but sometimes it's not a problem if you've applied but didn't really need to.

If you decide to apply, make sure that you keep a copy of your object somewhere with the modifiers non-applied (non-destructive version as Vklidu says). In case of problem you'll be able to come back to this version and easily change it. If you've forgotten to keep a non-destructive version, it may be tedious to rebuild the same object. But for example you can easily re-mirror an object, you just need to cut its half.

Sometimes during the modeling you'll need to apply a modifier because it's not always possible to make a non-destructive object from start to end with a huge stack of modifiers. Also sometimes it's more complicated to do something with modifiers than manually, don't always try to do everything with modifiers, but it's another problem...

The *Subdivision Surface* modifier is often not applied, because it makes your objects lighter and easier to edit. Sometimes you'll need to apply it though, for example to export to a game engine, or to 3D print.

Most of the time you won't apply the *Ocean* modifier, obviously, otherwise it will stop moving.

Etc... Actually you'll easily guess which one needs to be applied or not applied. At the beginning, in case of doubt, always make a copy of your object to keep a non-destructive version.